# Add custom fields to joomla frontend edit.php based on category

Tags: php, joomla

I added a few custom fields with a plugin to my joomla com_content articles. I need to edit these fields in the frontend editor but the fields should just appear based on the category. In case the field should just appear when i select category 43 in the frontend editor.

Actually the fields appear on all categories in above the articletext field.

edit.php:

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="editor">
    <?php echo $this->form->renderField('title'); ?>

    <?php if (is_null($this->item->id)) : ?>
        <?php echo $this->form->renderField('alias'); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <!-- custom fields -->
    <?php echo $this->form->renderField('typ', 'attribs'); ?>
    <?php echo $this->form->renderField('notizen', 'attribs'); ?>
    <!-- end custom fields -->

    <?php echo $this->form->getInput('articletext'); ?>
</div>
```

Can i use if else based on a category id in edit.php or is there another solution?

Comment: Please give the plugin name at least, or is it just a custom built plugin. it is important to know how the plugin is made as it is not easy to analyse with just a chunk of code. There can be more easier solutions if you can name that plugin.

Comment: I created the plugin by myself. The plugin is based on this tutorial: https://docs.joomla.org/Adding_custom_fields_to_core_components_using_a_plugin/de

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you will have access to the category in your form object. Try something like

```
$category = $this->form->getValue('catid');
$only_on_these = array(10, 20, 30); // special categories
if (in_array($category, $only_in_these)) {
  // render your custom fields
  echo $this->form->renderField('typ', 'attribs');
  echo $this->form->renderField('notizen', 'attribs');
}
...
```

This works for editing existing content, but you'll need to do some special handling for new articles, forcing them initialized with some categories, depending on how you want this to work.